# JavaScript dynamic import works on linux but fails on windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import

In the chrome extension the code snippet:

```
import("/lib.js").then((lib) => { const p = lib.getFoo() });
```

works fine in chrome browser on linux,
but it fails on windows with the error message
"Uncought (in promise) TypeError: lib.getFoo is not a function"

I would appreciate any ideas how to solve this issue.

UPDATES:

I put console.log("lib= ", lib) and I see a difference between Windows & Linux. On Linux & Windows I see:
`lib= |> Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'}`, however when I click on "|>" to expand `Module`, on Linux I see a list of items I would expect to see in `lib.js`, while on Windows I just see `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"`

> 1. Ensure that your Chrome extension has the appropriate permissions to access and load the lib.js file on Windows. Check the manifest.json file for any discrepancies between platforms.(https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015?hl=en)

I tried to get some info from the link above if/how manifest.json should be different between Windows & Linux, but no success so far...

> 2. Check if the encoding is the same for both platforms (for example, UTF-8).

- Linux: all `*.js` files are `"text/plain; charset=us-ascii"`
  as reported by `file -bi`
- Windows: `*.js` file have `UTF-8` encoding
  (as reported by Notepad), so, as I understand encoding, is the same...

> 3. Try using a static import...

Apparently I cannot use static import in `content.js` - I am getting `Cannot use import statement outside a module (at content.js:3:1)`.
I have

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "type": "module"
    }
  ],
```

in `manifest.json`, but despite this `content.js` apparently is not recognized as a module

> 4. If you're using bundler...

I am not using a bundler. Just `Load unpacked` in `chrome://extensions/`

> @ryszard as I see from you report above there is an issue with encodings. us-ascii and utf-8 are different encodings. Please try iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 input_file_name > output_file_name command to change file encoding on Linux and then move the file to Windows. UTF-8 is recommended encoding for web and it's backwards-compatible with ASCII. So, don't worry to break anything.

Hmm... Currently I see `us-ascii` on Linux side and `UTF-8` on Windows side. Original code is on Linux side, then uploaded to Github and "git cloneed" from Github to Windows laptop. When I run run iconv on Linux site I do not see any change:

```
$ iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 tmp.1.js > tmp.2.js
$ ls -lt tmp.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ryszard ryszard 2422 Mar 22 17:23 tmp.2.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ryszard ryszard 2422 Mar 22 17:22 tmp.1.js
$ file -bi tmp.2.js tmp.1.js 
text/x-java; charset=us-ascii
text/x-java; charset=us-ascii
```

Comment: Is there any difference if you'll try to inspect **lib** value with console.log() on different platforms?
import("/lib.js").then((lib) => { console.log(lib); });

If 'lib.js' is not your implementation, it's fairly common case to differentiate packages logic for Linux/Windows. I faced it a lot.

Comment: Use devtools to debug the code. Set a breakpoint inside `then` and inspect the value of `lib`.

Comment: I put console.log(

Comment: I put console.log("lib= ", lib) and I see a difference between Windows & Linux (I added details to the original question above) and apparently as @piskunovim mentioned ([...] it's fairly common case to differentiate packages logic for Linux/Windows[...]) this import has to be done differently for Windows, but exactly how? Could you provide any pointers? BTW: lib.js is the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated description I would suggest:

1. Ensure that your Chrome extension has the appropriate permissions to access and load the lib.js file on Windows. Check the manifest.json file for any discrepancies between platforms.(https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015?hl=en)
2. Check if the encoding is the same for both platforms (for example, UTF-8).
3. Try using a static import to see if the issue persists: `import * as lib from '/lib.js'`. It's possible that there might be differences in how dynamic imports are being handled on Windows and Linux.
4. If you're using bundler like Webpack, Gulp, etc. to build **lib.js**, check the configurations and plugins you're using to ensure they're not generating platform-specific code.

Comment: Added some more UPDATES above...

Comment: @ryszard as I see from you report above there is an issue with encodings. **us-ascii** and **utf-8** are different encodings. Please try ```iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 input_file_name > output_file_name``` command to change file encoding on Linux and then move the file to Windows. UTF-8 is recommended encoding for web and it's backwards-compatible with ASCII. So, don't worry to break anything.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but note that files on Windows are already UTF-8 encoded - also please see my comments in UPDATES above. Do you think executing what you suggested above can make any difference?